# OpenIdConnect wrong redirection after authentication and granting authorizations

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I've setup a .NET Core 2.0 webapp with Azure AD using OpenIdConnect (like this one: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore, all the OpenIDConnect configuration is located [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L31)).

I have the following scenario:

- call of http://localhost/my-api-function
- redirection to microsoftonline.com
- choose a Microsoft account I haven't already logged in to this app
- enter password
- accept the requested authorizations (the API app registration grants Graph API access to user profile). See the attached screenshot.
- I get redirected to http://localhost/signin-oidc with the following error:

  OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADSTS90008: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxx'. This happened because application is misconfigured: it must require access to Windows Azure Active Directory by specifying at least 'Sign in and read user profile' permission.

I think I may have an incorrect redirection after login. I expect to be redirected to http://localhost/my-api-function rather than http://localhost/signin-oidc

I have another working scenario:

- call of http://localhost/my-api-function
- redirection to microsoftonline.com
- choose a Microsoft account I have already logged in to this app then logged out
- enter password
- not prompted again to accept the requested authorizations (the API app registration grants Graph API access to user profile).
- I get redirected to http://localhost/my-api-function as expected and get my protected data.

In Azure AD, I've configured the following reply-url: http://localhost/signin-oidc and granted both "Windows Azure Active Directory" and "Microsoft Graph" APIs to "sign in and read user profile".

Thanks for any pointers.

[image: Permissions grant asked after login]

**Edit of 08/22:**
I understood that redirection seems to redirect to previous url in authentication flow so posted to [MS Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b7a726e-3b39-453e-8919-6031b9ee0cec/wrong-redirection-after-delegated-permission-user-consent?forum=WindowsAzureAD) with this more specific indication to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to grant permissions by clicking a button located above the permissions lists.

More details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b7a726e-3b39-453e-8919-6031b9ee0cec/wrong-redirection-after-delegated-permission-user-consent?forum=WindowsAzureAD)